# Long string in 32 Bytes?

Tags: android, algorithm, shell, compression

Is there any possibility to shorten/compress long string (alphanumeric & characters) in 32 Bytes buffer?

I have a device which send only 32 Bytes data at a time to Mobile (Android Application).
Device has a script which takes user input and send to mobile.
Android application receives that buffer in 'String' using specific SDK to display it.

Device has significant time gap between transmit of two 32 Bytes buffer. So even chunks of large String will not be proper solution, as that will add more delay to display large string.

So looking for option to put little long string in 32 Bytes, if possible.

One way for this can be mapping of user entered characters (ASCII 32 to ASCII 126) from 0 to 94 i.e. (binary 000 0000 to 101 1110). This will utilize 7 bits instead of 8 bits for each character. and will allow to transmit only 36 characters (32chars * 8bits / 7bits = 36.5 chars).

Comment: Entirely and completely depends on the data, you cannot put more than 32 bytes of data into 32 bytes of data.

Comment: To cut a long argument short: no. You can *select* one from a *huge* number of `long string`s *already known to the receiver* with `32 Bytes`. You can form quite a number of `long string`s using `32 Bytes` to select words from a dictionary *already known to the receiver*. For algorithms exploiting self-similarity "from scratch", 32 *characters* would be too short.